# Show that $(x_n)$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x)=\cos^n(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$

1) Show that $f_n$ has a unique fix point $x_n$ for all $n$.
2) Show that $(x_n)$ is decreasing a compute it's limit.

**My try**

1) No problem for this question since $f'<0$, $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<1$. Therefore it's a consequence of the intermediate value theorem.

2) I tried many things to show that $(x_n)$ is decreasing but with no success. For the limit, I would say $0$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Are you able to compute the explicit value of $x_n$ for a given $n$ in the first question? Then (2) may be a bit easier, as you for the moment don't have much to go on.

Comment: @Scounged: Of course not ! And I don't think that you can give an explicit value for $x_n$ ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that it was difficult when I tried. All I got was that $\cos(x)\geq 0$ on the interval, and thus that (when trying to get the fix point) $cos(x_n)=(x_n)^{1/n}$, or $x_n=\arccos((x_n)^{1/n})$, which I didn't really get anywhere with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g_n(x)=x-\cos^n(x)$ for all $x\in[0;1]$.

We have:
$$
\cos^{n+1}(x)≤\cos^n(x)\space\forall x\in(0;1]\implies\\
g_{n+1}(x)>g_n(x)\space\forall x\in(0;1]
$$
Therefore, we have $g_{n+1}(x_n)>g_n(x_n)=0$. Thus, we must have $x_{n+1}\in[0;x_n)$ and therefore $x_{n+1}<x_n$.

For the limit, we observe that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)=x$ for all $x\in(0;1]$, thus we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.

Edit:

A more precise argumentation for the limit:

The limit exists, because the sequence is decreasing and bounded below by $0$, so we call the limit $a$. If $a>0$, then the observation $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)=x$ for all $x\in(0;1]$ tells us, that there exists an $N$ for which $g_k(a)>0\implies a>x_k$ for all $k≥N$. This contradicts with the decreasing nature of $x_n$. Thus, $a$ must be $0$.

Comment: Thanks :-). I just don't see why $\lim_{n\to\infty }g_n(x)=x$ for all $x\in(0,1]\implies \lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=0$.

Comment: Everything okay now? :)

Comment: It is, thank you very much :-)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't contradict the fact that $(x_n)$ is decreasing (or I don't see how). To me the contradiction is the fact that $a=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$.

Comment: Yes, this what I meant by that. The fact that $a=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N} x_n$ is due to the fact that $x_n$ is decreasing.